# MPI printf and sending/receiving string

Tags: c, mpi, send

I am new at MPI. I am trying to send strings (later on would be file path) through Send and Recv. However, the output is weird. What am I doing wrong?

I have 2 machines named buckeye and paso (with buckeye as master). My host file is:

```
paso slots=4
buckeye slots=4
```

I compiled (the sourcefile helloworld.c below) with the following:

```
mpicc helloworld.c -o hello
```

Then I ran it with:

```
mpirun -np 8 --hostfile hosts ./hello "Test argument"
```

I have rank 4 -- master -- send the message "hello" to rank 5 (same machine) and then print it out. I also print out the rank and the name of processors. 
Here is the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d, out of %d processors...\n",
        processor_name, rank, world_size);
    //printf("Input argument is %s\n", argv[1]);

    /* communication */
    if (rank == 4){
        char * test  = "hello";
        printf("I am rank 4\n");
        MPI_Send(&test, 7, MPI_CHAR, 5, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else if (rank == 5){
        char * buf[10];
        MPI_Status status;
        int ierr;
        ierr = MPI_Recv(&buf, 7, MPI_CHAR, 4, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (ierr == MPI_SUCCESS)
            printf("Rank %d (processor %s) received value %s.\n", rank, processor_name, buf);
        else   
            printf("Rank %d (processor %s) did not sucessfully receive a value!\n", rank, processor_name);
    }
    else
        printf("I'm rank %d\n", rank);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I have 2 main questions:

1) Why is the value received by rank 5 bad?

2) Why don't rank 0-3 print out the second printf (i.e. "I'm rank x")? 
They print out the first line.

Here is the output

```
Hello world from processor buckeye, rank 4, out of 8 processors...
I am rank 4
Hello world from processor buckeye, rank 5, out of 8 processors...
Rank 5 (processor buckeye) received value a
                                           @.
Hello world from processor buckeye, rank 6, out of 8 processors...
I'm rank 6
Hello world from processor buckeye, rank 7, out of 8 processors...
I'm rank 7
Hello world from processor paso, rank 0, out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor paso, rank 1, out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor paso, rank 2, out of 8 processors
Hello world from processor paso, rank 3, out of 8 processors
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Generally, should `MPI_Send(&test, ...)` be `MPI_Send(test, ...)`? The first argument of `MPI_Send` is `const void *buf` with only a single `*`.

Comment: I get warnings about the printf statement when compiling with `-Wall`

Comment: ... but the argument you pass is from `char * test  = "hello";` which is already a pointer to read-only data.

Comment: @WeatherVane O yea. I did MPI_Send(test,...) but still get the same result.

Comment: Actually my bad, it works now. Thanks. Silly me. Do you know why my other processor doesn't print out the other messages then?

Comment: You also need to fix your use of `buf`

Comment: fwiw `"hello"` is only 6 `MPI_CHAR` long. (sending is very unlikely to cause any harm though)

Comment: `char * buf[10];` means array of pointers.
Replace it with `char buf[10]`